# Null pointer at setting setAdapter() in customadapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-asynctask, custom-adapter

I have two layouts for a single activity that I will dynamically change the layout. Here the null pointer occurs at the line.

1. I tried to change the view from layout 1 to layout 2
2. listview.setadapter(listviewAdapter)

   **lv2.setAdapter(lva);**

The error I am getting is

`java.lang.NullPointerException at in.prasilabs.eagleeye.Log$DBSync.onPostExecute(Log.java:170)`

```
public class Log extends Activity {

    ListView lv1;
    ListView lv2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.logmenu);

        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        final Activity act = getParent();

        String[] menu = new String[] 
        {
            "Last 10 log",
            "All logs (100)",

        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> menuadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, menu);

        lv1.setAdapter(menuadapter);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            DBSync dbs;
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    dbs = new DBSync(position, Log.this, act);
                    dbs.execute();
                    break;

                default:    
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class DBSync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        int q;
        String[] time = new String[]{"No logs"};
        String[] status = new String[]{"closed"};
        Context cnt;
        Activity act;
        public DBSync(int qu, Log lg, Activity ac) {
            q = qu;
            cnt = lg;
            act = ac;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {   
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //setContentView(R.layout.log);

        time = new String[]{"hii","yes"};
        status = new String[]{"no", "yes"};
        boolean isFirstXml=true;//evaluatingConditionFunction();
        LayoutInflater inflator=getLayoutInflater();
        View view=inflator.inflate(isFirstXml?R.layout.logmenu:R.layout.log, null, false);
        view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(cnt, android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
        **setContentView(view);**
        lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        ListViewAdapter lva = new ListViewAdapter(act, time, status);
        **lv2.setAdapter(lva);**
        lv2.refreshDrawableState();


        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: findViewById, setContentView, then using result of first findViewById? ... good luck

Comment: I tried a lot for working on these. and I am not getting the solution to solve the problem.

Comment: you're using `setContentView` twice.. this may cause `findViewById` to return null.. if you don't have the right components in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setContentView` twice.

```
setContentView(R.layout.log);
setContentView(R.layout.logmenu);
```

By calling it twice, only the second one (`R.layout.logmenu`) will be set. I guess `R.id.listView2` is in `R.layout.log`. Because of this, `(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2)` returns null and `lv2` gets null. When you try to call `lv2.setAdapter`, you try to set an adapter on an object that is null - Your app crashes.

Comment: Thanks. I got that. But i am seeing empty blank page instead of the listview.

Comment: When do you see an empty blank page? When you remove the second `setContentView` call?

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
    setContentView(R.layout.log);
    lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    time = new String[]{"hii","yes"};
    status = new String[]{"no", "yes"};
    boolean isFirstXml=true; 
    LayoutInflater inflator=getLayoutInflater();
    View view=inflator.inflate(isFirstXml?R.layout.logmenu:R.layout.log, null,false);
    view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(cnt,   android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
    setContentView(view);
    ListViewAdapter lva = new ListViewAdapter(act, time,status);
    lv2.setAdapter(lva);

Comment: Again, you use `setContentView` twice. `setContentView(R.layout.log)` at the beginning of `onPostExecute` and `setContentView(view)` at the end. The second one is overriding the first one.

Comment: if i removed the `setcontentview(R.layout.log)` that occur at the beginning then it again gives **null pointer exception**

Comment: Yeah, this is the same NPE as before. You are calling `findViewById` on a layout that does not contain `R.id.listView2`. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @ByteHamster Instead of calling another activity I want to display the result in same activity but in another Layout

Comment: Comment out this one and try again: `setContentView(view);`

Comment: Use the code that produced a blank page and comment out `setContentView(view)`, sorry.

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.log);
   lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
   
   time = new String[]{"1.10","2.20"};
   status = new String[]{"no", "yes"};
   boolean isFirstXml=true;//evaluatingConditionFunction();
   LayoutInflater inflator=getLayoutInflater();
   View view=inflator.inflate(isFirstXml?R.layout.logmenu:R.layout.log, null, false);
   view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(cnt, android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
   setContentView(view);`

Comment: IF i change the order too it gives NPE

Comment: 1. setContentView(R.layout.log);  2.lv2 = (ListView) find... 3.setContentView(view)

Comment: This is getting a too long conversation for the comments, sorry. Go through your code in `onPostExecute` step by step and think about which layout is currently applied and which views can be loaded from that layout. Use a debugger to run your program line by line and I am sure you will find the problem.